# First Homomorphism Theorem and terminology

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

I am not finding clear terminology in my abstract algebra book to be clear at least and my questions are simple. Consider the construction of a quotient group G':
\begin{equation}
  G/K = G'
\end{equation}

I know that $K$ can be shown to be isomorphic to the kernel of some homomorphism between $G$ and $G'$ (is there intuition behind this first homomorphism theorem?) Perhaps an example group would suffice. What is the proper terminology for $K$? Suppose $G, K$ and $G'$ were real numbers, then in arithmetic the terminology would be that $G$ is the divident, $K$ is the divisor and $G'$ is the quotient. What is the equivalent terminology in group theory?

Summarising:

1. What is the intuition behind $K$ being isomorphic to some kernel of a homomorphism between $G$ and $G'$?
2. What is the formal terminology for $K$?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: "I know that K can be shown to be isomorphic to the kernel of any homomorphism between G and G′". This cannot be shown, because it is not true. $K$ is the kernel of the canonical projection $G \to G'$. You cannot take any homomorphism (what about the trivial one, it has kernel $G$).

Comment: Still question 2 makes sense. I would call $K$ the "thing which we mod out" ;-).

Comment: by canonical, do you mean that $K$ must be a normal subgroup? I also changed my implicit quantifiers. That is why I meant to write...